# Dom_munger issue with Node 7.7.3 - Path must be a string

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to update an application to support Node -v 7.7.3. But when I am running the grunt task dom_munger as per below:

```
dom_munger:{
  read: {
    options: {
      read:[
        {selector:'script[data-concat!="false"]',attribute:'src',writeto:'appjs', isPath: true},
        {selector:'link[rel="stylesheet"][data-concat!="false"]',attribute:'href',writeto:'appcss'}
      ]
    },
    src: 'app/index.html'
  }
}
```

I receive error:

```
Warning: Path must be a string. Received [ 'app/index.html' ] Use --force to continue.
```

I wonder if there is a way to rewrite above grunt task or if there might be a good alternative to dom_munger. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Per the `grunt-dom-munger` Github:

> When `isPath` is true, the extracted values are assumed to be file
>   references and their path is made relative to the Gruntfile.js rather
>   than the file they're read from.

Try removing the `isPath` property, or altering it to match the path from your Gruntfile to the index.html file.

Comment: Thanks you! But this only seems to work if the Grunt and Index are in the same folder structure. My structure looks like this:

    - /app
        -index.html
    - gruntfile.js

And without the attribute 'isPath' the dom_munger will look for js files in the same directory as where the Gruntfile is places.

Comment: @sandrasvensson But did you try removing the `isPath` property? It seemed to solve [this similar issue](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger/issues/42).

Answer (score 1):

Remove isPath: true, and make sure that path in src attribute relative to the Gruntfile.js rather than the file they're read from.

If needs make a replace in path:

```
dom_munger: {
  replacePath: {
    options: {
      callback: function($, file){
        var scripts = $('script[data-concat!="false"]');
        // NOTE: path is made relative to the Gruntfile.js rather than the file they're read from
        for(var i=0, s, il=scripts.length; i<il; i++){
          s = scripts[i];
          if(s.attribs.src){
            s.attribs.src = s.attribs.src.replace('../', '');
          }
        }
      }
    },
    src: 'temp/index.html'
  },
  read: {
    options: {
      read: [
        {selector:'script[data-concat!="false"]',attribute:'src',writeto:'appjs'},
        {selector:'link[rel="stylesheet"][data-concat!="false"]',attribute:'href',writeto:'appcss'}
      ]
    },
    src: 'temp/index.html'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you! But this only seems to work if the Grunt and Index are in the same folder structure. My structure looks like this:

```
- /app
    -index.html
- gruntfile.js
```

And without the attribute 'isPath' the dom_munger will look for js files in the same directory as where the Gruntfile is places.